# How the compiler optimization solves this programming issue?

Tags: c, function, return-value, compiler-optimization

Let us consider the following program.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define EXIT_SUCCESS 0
#define EXIT_FAILURE 1

int square_of(const int value)
{
    // int expr = value * value;
    // return expr;
}

int main(void)
{
    int test_val = 15;
    int res = square_of(test_val);

    fprintf(stdout, "The square of %d is %d.\n", test_val, res);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output without using the optimization flag is as follows:

```
The square of 15 is 15.
```

However, when the optimization is used, for example, `-O1`, `-O2`, `-O3`, the issue is fixed, and the output is as expected:

```
The square of 15 is 0.
```

I am unable to understand why the program is behaving this way. Is it an undefined behavior or something else?

---

**Note:** I am aware of the control reaching non-void function warning:

```
main.c: In function ‘square_of’:
main.c:10:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   10 | }
      | ^
```

Comment: Why is 0 the expected output? The behavior is undefined.

Comment: Which compiler? BTW you should turn on the warnings.

Comment: @kiner_shah GCC 9.3.0. Please refer to the note mentioned in the question.

Comment: ***the output is as expected*** for some reason, -O1 or -O2 doesn't generate assembly: https://godbolt.org/z/dh13d4xxE

Comment: The question is unclear. Why is 15 and 0 "expected"? Expected by whom? Why? Also any answer will be a very uninteresting variation of "undefined behavior is behavior which is not defined".

Comment: @Lundin The value 15 is never expected. I was confused about whether this was an undefined behavior or not. So, I expected zero as the desired result.

Comment: @kiner_shah: You compiled it *as C++*, where it's UB for control to reach the end of a non-void function.  This is a C question, where it's only UB to actually use the return value.  (Early C didn't have `void`, and ISO C still hasn't fully broken backwards compat with code that uses `int` for functions that don't actually return anything.)  Anyway, the compiler can assume that paths of execution which would definitely encounter UB won't ever execute, so it can save code size by not generating code for them.  (This is potentially helpful in real-world branchy code, unlike here.)  Use `g++ -xc`

Comment: GCC in C mode would be allowed to generate no code for main due to the C UB of using the non-existent return value.  But for some reason GCC chooses to do things differently and zero out variables that are read uninitialized.  This is of course 100% arbitrary, and I have no idea why anyone would "expect" that instead of for example some garbage value from a register or memory.

Comment: @PeterCordes, ohh yeah, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `square_of` has no `return` statement while it is declared to return an `int` value: using the return value is Undefined Behaviour. On most common compilers, you will get an unpredictable value, but standard does not even prevent trap values.

You get either the original value (without optimizations) or a 0 value only *by chance* or *by accident* and should not rely on it.

**Warning are not to be ignored**. As a compiler is allowed to assume that the code should not contain UB, it is free to optimize out any code where UB can be detected...

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks for the clarification. Well, I intentionally ignored the warning, but I did not know that it was an UB.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply undefined behavior, anything can happen and there is no expected result - see [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486)

Specifically, it is explicitly undefined behavior as per C17 6.9.1/11:

> If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.